# Check if a list contains a key

Tags: python

I am trying to check if a list contains a key.

I have a dictionary that I have sorted and believe it turns it into a list. Now I want to check that list for a key.

**Here is my code to give an idea where I am:**

```
drinkDict = {'drink1': drinkTimes[0],'drink2': drinkTimes[1],'drink3': drinkTimes[2],'drink4': drinkTimes[3],'drink5': drinkTimes[4]};
    print drinkDict
    for k, v in drinkDict.items():
        if v == '0':
            del drinkDict[k]
    sorted_x = sorted(drinkDict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    print sorted_x
    print (sorted_x[0]
    if 'drink1' in sorted_x.key:
        print "drink1 is present"
        data = pin_update(VALID_BCM_PIN_NUMBERS[0], 0)
```

**Output**:

```
{'drink4': u'4.8', 'drink5': u'0.7', 'drink1': u'1.4', 'drink2': u'2.8', 'drink3': u'0'}
[('drink5', u'0.7'), ('drink1', u'1.4'), ('drink2', u'2.8'), ('drink4', u'4.8')]
('drink5', u'0.7')
```

I just can't figure out how to detect if sorted_x contains "drink1" or "drink2" etc. etc.

I am not sure on terminology here so please correct me if I'm wrong so I can better search for solutions.

Comment: What's the point of converting to a list and sorting? The lookup is much easier if you keep it as a dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reuse `operator.itemgetter` from earlier, except we are looking at the first (0th) entry this time:

```
'drink1' in map(operator.itemgetter(0), sorted_x) # True
```

However, you might want to explain why you are doing all of this. It seems like you're dancing around different data structures and I'm not sure for what reason.

To sort the items in the dictionary by the second value:

```
sortedItems = sorted(drinkDict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

In general, it looks like you could achieve the same thing using code like:

```
import operator

drinkDict = {'drink1': '2', 
             'drink2': '1', 
             'drink3': '4',
             'drink4': '3',
             'drink5': '0'
            }

# removes 'drink5': '0'
filteredDict = {k: v for k, v in drinkDict.items() if v != '0'}

# [('drink2', '1'), ('drink1', '2'), ('drink4', '3'), ('drink3', '4')]
sortedItems = sorted(filteredDict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
```

Comment: I am trying to get more than just the min value. I need to know which is the next smallest and so on for the 5 drinks

Comment: Is sortedItems a dictionary?

Comment: @BluGeni No, it's a list of 2-tuples as shown in the comment directly above it. If you want a sorted dictionary you need to use something like `OrderedDict` from `collections` as dictionaries do not guarantee the order of the keys. You can always test things by running the code in an interpreter and do things like `type(sortedItems)`.

Comment: ok thanks for the explanation but I think this leaves me exactly where I was not knowing how to check if drink1 is in the list

Comment: @BluGeni go back to the first line of my answer... `'drink1' in map(operator.itemgetter(0), sortedItems)`. Go run the code in an interpreter and then look at what `map(operator.itemgetter(0), sortedItems)` produces.

Answer (score 0):

You have printed the first item of `sorted_x`, and you can see it's a tuple, not a string. Checking if the string `'drink_1'` is in `sorted_x` is never going to work.

As Daniel noted in the comment, you probably don't want to work with a sorted list of tuples, it's much easier to do lookups on the dict you have:

```
if 'drink1' in drinkDict:
   ...
```

Also note that you sort on the values, which are strings and not numbers. That means that you sort them alphabetically and not numerically. You might want to adjust the sorting key to convert them to float, or just store them as floats to begin with.

Comment: how can I know which dictionary value is the smallest?

Comment: @BluGeni Is that your goal?